# Butterworth Kernel Generation

Tags: python, python-3.x, matlab, signal-processing, butterworth

I want to apply the butterworth filter on a image in order to remove the blur. How can I generate a butterworth kernel from the filter coefficients (a and b in the below code).

```
def butterLow(cutoff, critical, order):
    normal_cutoff = float(cutoff) / critical
    b, a = signal.butter(order, normal_cutoff, btype='lowpass')
    return b, a
```

Thank you!

Comment: Butterworth filters have an infinite impulse response (IIR). Do you really want to apply that to an image? Filters to be applied to images are usually FIR (and 2D)

Comment: You can apply a filter in the form "b, a" to an image by calling [signal.lfilter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html) twice, one time to apply along rows (axis=0) and another time to apply along columns (axis=1). But are you sure that's what you want to do? The filter in your post is a lowpass filter, so applying it would have the effect of blurring image. Yet you say you want to *remove the blur*.